# Drupal 7 subfolder multisite

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I'm trying to setup a drupal 7 multisite using subfolders for example:

example.com/site1

example.com/site2

In my drupal sites folder I have sites1 and sites2 according to sites.php I should be able to set it up as the following:

```
$sites['example.com/site1'] = 'site1';
$sites['example.com/site2'] = 'site2';
```

However this doesn't work, I can definitely see a site at example.com but am unable to see any of the sites in the sub folder.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to expose the subsites as directories? It is usually far better to setup a subdomain, such as site1.example.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do it this way then you have to symlink the folder to the root of the drupal install:

```
cd /var/www/drupal
ln -s . site1
```

Then within sites.php use the following:

```
$sites = array(
    "example.com.site1" => "site1",
);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example where you have "/subdirect" and "sitename.com", both being called site1 doesnt let us know what to do when you want diff path's and sites :)

Comment: Answered my own question. If you have /subdir and site.com then it would be create a sym link for subdir in drupal root, then in sites.php. $domain . '.subdir' => 'site.com' the / must be a . - very important and tripped me up before i found this!

Comment: PS! I think this question is answered quite good in the documentation on Drupal.org - see https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/multi-site-in-subdirectories